# UWSim, Ubuntu 12.04, ros-fuerte installation problem

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install UWSim in Ubuntu 12.04 with fuerte installed. I checked out the repository from here

```
svn checkout http://uji-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/underwater_simulation underwater_simulation
```

I then run:

```
rosdep install UWSim
```

The outcome of this is:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
UWSim: No definition of [libopenscenegraph] for OS version [precise]
```

I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. I even installed libopenscenegraph (and dependencies) from the synaptic but nothing.

When I had a look at the rosdep.yaml file there was no reference to the precise distro (the latest was oneiric). Still despite the fact that I added it myself nothing changed. Any ideas on what is going on?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

P.S I also tried Ubuntu 10.04 and electric and it worked just fine. (The simulator is up and running) But I need 12.04 and fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45429/uwsim,-ubuntu-12.04,-ros-fuerte-installation-problem/) by [George P](https://answers.ros.org/users/2902/george-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the rosdep rule for libopenscenegraph under precise was missing (we are still in oneiric). I've checked that someone just added it, so you shouldn't get this error now (after doing a 'rosdep update').

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [George P](https://answers.ros.org/users/2902/george-p/) on 2012-10-11**:
Thank you very much for your reply I got it working